# H2 connection pool

Tags: java, h2, apache-commons-dbcp

I want to make a connection pool for my h2 database. But I think my pool opens new connection every time I call `getConnection()`. I guess there should be a fixed amount of reusable connections, but if I run this code :

```
Connection conn = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM NODE_USERS;");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("login"));
        }
        try {
            // wait a bit
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
```

DataSource:

```
public class DataSource {

    private static volatile DataSource datasource;
    private BasicDataSource ds;

    private DataSource() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setUsername("sa");
        ds.setPassword("sa");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test");       
        ds.setMinIdle(5);
        ds.setMaxActive(10);
        ds.setMaxIdle(20);
        ds.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(180);

    }

    public static DataSource getInstance() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        if (datasource == null) {
            synchronized (DataSource.class) {
                if (datasource == null) {
                    datasource = new DataSource();
                }
            }
            datasource = new DataSource();
        }
        return datasource;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return this.ds.getConnection();
    }

}
```

and then execute `select * from information_schema.sessions;`, there will be two rows. What is wrong? Also I was trying H2 [tutorial example](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connection_pool), but I've got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a connection pool, namely `BasicDataSource`. It will create a configured number of connections initially and then when `getConnection()` is called, it will either reused a free pooled connection or create a new one, up to a configured limit (or no limit if configured so). When the connection obtained is "closed" using `Connection.close()`, it is actually returned to the pool instead of being closed right away.

You basically have no control over how many open connctions there will be at a given time, apart of configuring the minimum and maximum allowed open connections. You observing two open connections therefore doesn't prove anything. If you want to see whether there is a limit on open connections, configure the `BasicDataSource` to use at most 2 connections using [`BasicDataSource.maxActive()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html#maxActive), then try to obtain three connections at the same time. And for another test, with the same configuration, try obtaining two connections, returning them using `Connection.close()` and then obtaining another two connections.